# merging two cvHistograms in opencv

Tags: opencv, merge, computer-vision, histogram

Is there a way to merge two CvHistograms?
Say we have CvHistogram* hist1 and CvHistogram* hist2.

Then, is there an automated way to produce a third histogram (hist3) with the addition of each color appearance on hist1 and hist2, or do I have to do it manually?

Many thanks,
Dimos.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Disappointing, but there is no handy function to do that for you.

But, if you want to use the C++ interface, the histogram is stored in a mat object. And you can usee all the function and operators define for matrices.

And you'll can do

```
h3 = h1 + h2;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.

Actually there is the  cvAdd( const CvArr* A, const CvArr* B, CvArr* C, const CvArr* mask=0) function, where you can merge two histograms!